# getting a header with two alignments in apache fop

Tags: apache, xsl-fo, apache-fop

In xsl:fo i'm trying to create a header that contains the company name and the print date. The company name should be aligned to the left and the print date should be aligned to the right. Somhow i can not get this to work.

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
  <fo:block text-align="start" position="absolute" top="0">
    initech
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block text-align="end" position="absolute" top="0">
    Printdate 11-04-2011
  </fo:block>           
</fo:static-content>
```

Could anyone give me some tips on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
  <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
initech<fo:leader/>Printdate 11-04-2011
  </fo:block>           
</fo:static-content>
```